# How to access aerospike-client-rest /v3/api-docs

Tags: docker, rest, swagger-ui, aerospike

I tried to run aerospike-client-rest in Docker.
following the steps from this [github link](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-rest/blob/master/docs/installation-and-config.md)

1. docker build -t aerospike-client-rest .
2. docker run -itd --rm -p 8080:8080 --name AS_Rest1 -e aerospike_restclient_hostname=172.17.0.3 aerospike-client-rest

Was able to access the following:

- http://localhost:8080/v1/cluster
- http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
- http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

But not http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs

Answer (score 2):

The latest version is available on Docker Hub.
https://hub.docker.com/r/aerospike/aerospike-client-rest/tags

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Aerospike REST Client are you using?

Open API 3 support was added in version 1.10.0 (latest is 1.10.4).
Anything prior to that uses the Swagger 2 documentation which explains why you are able to access http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs instead of http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.

Comment: latest on this dockerhub link https://hub.docker.com/r/aerospike/aerospike-client-rest

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue, we will upload the latest version of Aerospike REST Client to dockerhub.